# Angular 10 on IIS - cannot open link (component) in new tab, always redirected to index/404.0 error displayed

Tags: angular, iis, angular-ui-router

In my Angular application deployed on IIS I want to open link 'Contact' in new tab via the following link:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/contact']">Contact</a>
```

The problem is that in the new tab I find index page. Previously I had a problem with refreshing page which I solved by this given to `web.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

After reading many inputs on stackoverflow and elsewhere I suspect this setting to be responsible for this behavior, but am not sure.

Is there a way to combine correct behavior of refresh and ability to open link in new tab in Angular app deployed to IIS?

**EDIT**

Now I understand the construction. It means if I try to access anything except file or directory, my request is redirected to index.html.

I added (prepended) another rule to avoid redirecting:

```
<rule name="Contact link" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="contact" />
  <action type="None" />
</rule>
```

This ensures that any request to contact page is not redirected. But at the same time, for obvious reason, I get a 404.0 error, because no index file is found at that location.

So new question is: *Is there any way how to open angular component in new tab?*

Comment: FRT might give you some hints, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: @LexLi Thank you very much for this link. It lead my ideas the right way. I edited the question - do you know the answer? :)

Comment: Did you open the link 'Contact' in a new tab, but got a 404 error? and this Contact is an A tag in the page, If so, then you need to use the outbound rule to rewrite the Contact. [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-outbound-rules-for-url-rewrite-module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-outbound-rules-for-url-rewrite-module)